# How to annotate a type that is a combination of multiple duck-types?

Tags: python, annotations, python-typing, typing, duck-typing

Let's say I want to annotate the parameter to a function, and it should satisfy both `typing.Sized` and `typing.Hashable` (any other 2+ types could apply, I just picked these two for the sake of example). How would I annotate this?

Given that one can combine types as an "or" using `Sized | Hashable`, I would expect something like: `Sized & Hashable` or `Sized + Hashable` to work, but unfortunately it doesn't (at the time of writing on Python 3.10).

Is this supported at all, and if so with what syntax?

Comment: If you want to add multiple different types can you not just use the `Union` class from the `typing` library, use it like this `val: Union[...]` with commas to seperate.

Comment: @xihtyM `Union` represents a type that can be *either* `Sized` or `Hashable`, but not necessarily both.

Comment: @xihtyM That's not a valid use of `list`.

Comment: True, I took a look at your answer and that seems to be the best way for both types.

Comment: A Union would be equivalent to `Type1 | Type2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sized & Hashable` is a reasonable guess, but unfortunately intersection types are not supported.

You'll have to define your own subclass that inherits from both:

```
class SizedHashable(Sized, Hashable):
    pass
```

---

There seems to be [some effort](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213#issuecomment-984021338) being made to support intersection types, but I can't find any updates beyond this brief mention.